# UsernameTokenHeader for WCF service

Tags: wcf

I am new WCF service. Here I am trying to add wsse:Security UsernameToken Header in wcf request message but I don't know how to do that and the rest of the things. It would be much appreciated if someone could help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom header by implementing the IDispatchMessageInspector interface. IDispatchMessageInspector is the interface implemented by the server. The client needs to implement the IClientMessageInspector interface.

**Here is my Demo:**

```
public class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Username", "http://Username", "Username");
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
        }
    }
```

This is the header added in the SOAP message.If you need to add a header to the http request, refer to the following code:

```
public class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
        {
            public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
            {

                return null;
            }

            public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
                WebOperationContext Context = WebOperationContext.Current;
                Context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            }
        }
```

CustomMessageInspector implements the IDispatchMessageInspector interface, and adds a custom header to the message after getting the message, and also adds a custom header before sending the message.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
    public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            return;
        }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
      dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

We add this interceptor to the behavior of the service.

[image]

Finally we apply Custombehavior to our service.