# BizTalk WCF-WebHTTP REST Client with Body and Header Sign with static port

Tags: rest, wcf, biztalk

I need to write REST client to service (lets call it REST SERVICE) that requires Custom Headers and JSON body.

Two of the headers have to have signature calculated based on other values from headers (which are also dynamic) and whole JSON body.

I also host a web service that will be used to serve my clients. In body of my service there are values that I need to pass to headers of REST SERVICE.

I made a dynamic WCF-WebHTTP port and whole header calculation made in message assignment in orchestration. It works, but I want to create static port.
How to achieve body and header inspection - how to calculate signature of request body and pass the result to header of the same request with static WCF-WebHTTP port?

Comment: If you need to add a custom header, you can implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface or the IClientMessageInspector interface. The IDispatchMessageInspector interface needs to be implemented on the server side, and the IClientMessageInspector is implemented on the client side. For more information about IDispatchMessageInspector, please refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @DingPeng I couldnt read the http body. I get <binary> some hashed text < /binary> xml instead of well formed one.

Comment: Did you not call the service through the proxy class?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I would like to inspect Message request object in BeforeSendRequest method in my custom behavior class like in this sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631372/wcf-iclientmessageinspector-beforesendrequest-modify-request

Comment: Don't you know how to apply BeforeSendRequest method to your service?

Comment: Yes. I added my custom behaviour to GAC , machine.config and applied to send port in Biztalk Admin Console.

Comment: You can refer to this link, which contains how to apply IDispatchMessageInspector to the service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775143/usernametokenheader-for-wcf-service/62790254#62790254

Comment: I was able to inspect http Headers like in Your example, but problem is in http body. Im not able to read body in my behaviour. Body looks like it is encoded somehow

Comment: Actually I workaround this passing whole body to Message Context and read that context in behavior - It works , but I'm still curious what is wrong with reading body  from Message object

Comment: This is related to the encoding you use, you should use binary encoding, if you want to see the message content, you need to use text encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to accomplish this with my custom Behavior.

Trick was to decode binary form of body from as it turns out base64 encoding

Here the samplecode how I manipulate the body:

```
private Message TransformMessage2(Message oldMessage) { 

Message newMessage = null; 

MessageBuffer msgbuf = oldMessage.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

Message tmpMessage = msgbuf.CreateMessage();

XmlDictionaryReader xdr = tmpMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(); 

xdoc.Load(xdr); xdr.Close(); 

byte[] bodyByte = Convert.FromBase64String(xdoc.InnerXml.ToString().Replace("<Binary>", "").Replace("</Binary>", ""));

String bodyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyByte, 0, bodyByte.Length); 

bodyString = bodyString.Replace("1234321", "9999999"); 

bodyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyString);

bodyString = "<Binary>" + Convert.ToBase64String(bodyByte) + "</Binary>"; 

xdoc = new XmlDocument(); 

xdoc.LoadXml(bodyString); 

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 

XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);

xdoc.Save(xw); xw.Flush(); xw.Close();  ms.Position = 0; 

XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(ms);

newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(oldMessage.Version, null, xr);   newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(oldMessage); 

newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(oldMessage.Properties); 

return newMessage;  }
```